# What is the correct way to initialize a pointer in c?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between the following initialization of a pointer?

```
char array_thing[10];

char *char_pointer;
```

what is the difference of the following initialization?

```
1.) char_pointer = array_thing;

2.) char_pointer = &array_thing
```

Is the second initialization even valid?

Comment: @k-ballo Not sure how you're coming to the conclusion that it's homework.

Comment: it's not homework..i'm just trying to learn C..

Comment: @K-ballo: Not everyone who is asking basic questions is trying to cheat through academic informatics, there are some people out there who actually want to learn.

Comment: @K-ballo: That's why I started my comment with "If", I wasn't accusing anyone, it just struck me as homework.

Comment: +1 for asking. Understanding stuff like this is important if you want to learn C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second initialization is not valid.  You need to use:

```
char_pointer = array_thing;
```

or

```
char_pointer = &array_thing[0];
```

`&array_thing` is a pointer to an array (in this case, type `char (*)[10]`, and you're looking for a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: The second initialization may still work, though, but it should throw a warning about the pointer types being incompatible.

Comment: @Dmitri, pointer conversions (except to or from `void *`) without explicit typecasts are illegal in C.  **6.5.4 Cast operators**, paragraph 3: "Conversions that involve pointers...shall be specified by means of an explicit cast."

Comment: @CarlNorum, That may be but some compilers will allow it.  I tried it with gcc, and it gave a warning, but compiled and ran fine.  So it's not proper, but "may still work".

Comment: gcc allows lots of things that are invalid C, and that's a large part of the reason so much C code (especially FOSS) is total crap...

Answer (score 1):

See comp.lang.c FAQ, Question 6.12: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are no initializations at all in the code you posted. That said, you should keep in mind that arrays decay to pointers (a pointer to the first element within the array). Taking the address of an array is certainly valid, but now you have a `(*char)[10]` instead of a `char*`.

Comment: Arrays (i.e., expressions of array type) decay to pointers *in most contexts* (as you implicitly acknowledge).  The exceptions are: the operand of a unary `&` operator, the operand of a unary `sizeof` operator, and a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object (e.g., `char s[] = "hello";`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're setting char_pointer to the first element of array_thing (the address of it, rather).  Using pointer arithmetic will bring you to other elements, as will indexing.  For example

```
char_pointer[3] = 'c';
```

is the same as

char_pointer += 3;
   char_pointer = 'c';

The second example...I don't believe that's valid the way you're doing it.